# Using Selenium -- how iterate Trello cards in a specific column?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, trello

So no code yet, but does anyone know w/ Selenium how I can:

1) Check if a Trello card exists in a specific column. (Yes I'm aware of XPATH and selectors :) )
2) **Iterate** all the cards in that column while cards exist (to perform actions involving each card).

I want to automate a work project with Selenium (which I'm fairly comfortable with but I can't figure out how to loop through elements in a column on Trello.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some rough Python code to get started with Trello -- this question is pretty generic, so I'm not sure what your end goal is here:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# navigate to trello
driver = webdriver.Chrome();
driver.get("https://trello.com/b/hLMqdeiE/welcome-to-trello")

# you probably need to log in here
# select a board?

# get list of cards in a column
# 'Things To Do' is the name of my list in trello.
cards_for_column = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[textarea[text()='Things To Do']]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class, 'list-cards')]/a")

for card in cards_for_column:

    # print URL to edit the card
    print(card.get_attribute("href"))
```

If you want a more specific answer, it would be best to get started on your own so that we can get a better idea of what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and concise answer/example Christine! I'm trying to iterate through all the cards of a specific column so that I can extract the info from each card as well as click links in each card to go to another site and extract info from those sites and then return to the board. My first and biggest issue is/was just understanding how I can iterate the cards, didn't think it would be as simple as that! I'll give it a shot! Thanks :)

Comment: The solution will get tricky once you click cards to edit them, because (depending on how Trello works), your reference to `card` in `cards_for_column` may go stale & throw `StaleElementReference`-- meaning you would need to keep track of `card` variable through an index (rather than a foreach) and re-do the `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` statement inside the loop each time. Feel free to post another question if you run into any issues with your code.

Comment: I think it's better to use [Trello APIs](https://developers.trello.com)?

Comment: The original poster specifically asked for a Selenium example, so that’s what I provided. If they would like to take an API approach, they can re-format their question with that context in mind.